# Memory dump doesn't show details for IIS crash

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7, windbg, windows-server-2008-r2

I rolled out a new version of my web application. Something in the new version has caused IIS to start crashing and I can't determine what code is causing it.

Using information from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx), I enabled automatic crash dumps.

Then after successfully creating a crash dump, I used the instructions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019674/how-to-debug-crashed-dump-file), using WinDbg,  to try and determine what happened.

After I found the thread that crashed and ran a !pe (thread) on it, it shows that it's a result of a StackOverflow. However no details are given:

```
0:064> !pe 00000001bfda01f0
Exception object: 00000001bfda01f0
Exception type:   System.StackOverflowException
Message:          <none>
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated): <none>
StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 800703e9
```

As you can see, there is no exception information or stacktrace.

Is there a step I'm missing to make sure this information either gets captures, or to show up in WinDbg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How I found the source of a StackOverflow exception in the past:

1. Open WinDbg, and Open Crash Dump and locate the dump file.
2. In the command line, type `.loadby sos clr`
3. Now type `!CLRStack`

Source: http://mikesmithdev.com/blog/debug-stack-overflow-exception/

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. The !CLRStack was the command I was missing. Also, your blog link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AaronS yeah site is responding like crap today (thanks godaddy)... Gotta get on them for that. Glad it helped tho, this issue was a pain in my side for a while.